# Cannot compile due has private access and error happens only in IntelliJ Idea based IDE

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I'm trying IntellJ IDEA with android SDK by a week, today I have tried to compile a new project and I get this error

```
java: java.util.LinkedHashMap.Entry has private access in java.util.LinkedHashMap
```

related to

```
private final HashMap<String, Bitmap> sHardBitmapCache = new LinkedHashMap<String, Bitmap>(HARD_CACHE_CAPACITY / 2,
        0.75f, true) {
    @Override
    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(LinkedHashMap.Entry<String, Bitmap> eldest) {
        if (size() > HARD_CACHE_CAPACITY) {
            sSoftBitmapCache.put(eldest.getKey(), new SoftReference<Bitmap>(eldest.getValue()));
            return true;
        } else
            return false;
    }
};
```

Comment: What if you use the interface: `Map.Entry<String, Bitmap> eldest`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your method use the interface `Map` instead:

```
private final Map<String, Bitmap> sHardBitmapCache = new LinkedHashMap<String, Bitmap>(HARD_CACHE_CAPACITY / 2,
        0.75f, true) {

    @Override
    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry<String, Bitmap> eldest) {
        if (size() > HARD_CACHE_CAPACITY) {
            sSoftBitmapCache.put(eldest.getKey(), new SoftReference<Bitmap>(eldest.getValue()));
            return true;
        } else
            return false;
    }
};
```

This is a public nested interface on `Map` as seen here:

[java.util.Map Source Code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Map.java#Map.Entry)

You will notice that the nested static class in `LinkedHashMap` is private as seen here:

[java.util.LinkedHashMap Source Code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedHashMap.java#LinkedHashMap.Entry)

Comment: But in Eclipse this compile without problems and runs without errors or crash. Why?

Comment: Are you using the same jdk for both ides?  Eclipse gives me an error when I import your code.

Comment: @AndreaF Glad you found it!